# isComputed property doesn't return expected value

Tags: knockout-2.0

I've been banging my head against the desk for a while -- and searched far and wide for an answer to my problem. I have an isComputed property in a KO viewmodel in which I'm trying to concatenate properties of a child collection. However, it stubbornly returns a boolean value... I know I must be missing something really simple!

I'm just looking for a pointer as to what I'm doing wrong here:

```
self.allWorkcenters = ko.isComputed(function() {
    var centers = "";
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.locationScans(), function(item) {
        var wc = item.workCenter.code();
        centers += "\r\n" + wc;
    });

    /*
        expecting something like "vutek, vutek, packing, finishing"
    */
    return centers;
});
```

The whole object and data are here: http://jsfiddle.net/austriacus/mGAcU/

UPDATE: I'm an idiot... I used isComputed instead of computed. DUH. Ok, it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/austriacus/mGAcU/16/

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Funny how this works sometimes. Updated original question with the working fiddle link